# From Throughput stacked bar chart want to show minimum, maximum and average values rally

Tags: extjs, extjs4, rally

I have created throughput stacked bar chart
From this chart want to get minimum, maximum and average value. And want it display on labels. But not able to figure out how to do it..any help on this please
[image]

```
var chart = Ext.getCmp('mychart'); // chart object
field = Ext.getCmp('myFieldId2'); // Labelfield Id
field.text = chart.chartConfig.yField.maximum;
```

This is the some code I tried to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get the values,

`this.globalVar = Ext.Array.flatten(tempSeries);`
globalVar has series and categories values for the chart

then called showStats(chart) function

```
showStats: function(chart) {
var project_oid = this.getContext().getProject().ObjectID;
//var chart = this.down('#display_box').add(this.getChartConfig(project_oid));
this.timePeriod = Rally.util.DateTime.getDifference(this._endDate, this._startDate,'month');
if (this.timePeriod == 0){
    this.timePeriod = 1;
};
var average = Ext.Array.mean(chart.calculator.globalVar);
average = Ext.Number.toFixed(average, 2);
var stdDev = this.standardDeviation(average, chart.calculator.globalVar);   
stdDev = Ext.Number.toFixed(stdDev, 2);     
this.down('#averageId').setText("Average" + " " + average); 
this.down('#countId').setText("Count"+ Ext.Array.sum(chart.calculator.globalVar));  
this.down('#minId').setText("Minimum"+ Ext.Array.min(chart.calculator.globalVar));  
this.down('#maxId').setText("Maximum"+ Ext.Array.max(chart.calculator.globalVar));  
this.down('#stdDevId').setText("Standard Deviation"+ stdDev);                   
this.down('#myFieldId').setText("Summary Metrics" + "(Last"+ this.timePeriod + months"+ ")");   
},      
standardDeviation: function(average, values){
   var squareDiffs = values.map(function(value){
     var diff = value - average;
     var sqrDiff = diff * diff;
     return sqrDiff;
   });
  var avgSquareDiff = Ext.Array.mean(squareDiffs);
  var stdDev = Math.sqrt(avgSquareDiff);
  return stdDev;
},
```